# Multidimensional array from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, product_types and products, and I am trying to make a multidimensional array that puts the products into their own product_type arrays within the main array.  The products have a product_type value that i can match them with.  I am using php and mysql to get the information.  My problem is that if I have more than one product assigned to one product_type then its only showing one of them.  Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
foreach ($type_array as $key => $type):
       foreach ($product_array as $k =>$product):
           if($product['product_type'] == $type){
             $variables[$type][] = $product;
           }
       endforeach;
endforeach;
```

My arrays:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Getting Skin Ready: Cleanse
    [1] => Getting Skin Ready: Scrub
    [2] => Getting Skin Ready: Oil Control/Tone
    [3] => Treatment
    [4] => Hydration and Calming
    [5] => Sun Protection
    [6] => Enhancers
    [7] => Programs and Kits
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 10
            [product_name] => 050100 NormacleanseTM Cleanser for Normal to Dry Skin
            [product_price] => 26.95
            [product_size] => 240 mL / 8 Fl. Oz.
            [product_type] => Sun Protection
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 11
            [product_name] => 050002 OilacleanseTM Cleanser for Normal to Oily Skin
            [product_price] => 26.95
            [product_size] => 240 mL / 8 Fl. Oz.
            [product_type] => Getting Skin Ready: Cleanse 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [product_name] => 052200 FoamacleanseTM Gentle Foaming Cleanser
            [product_price] => 26.95
            [product_size] => 240 mL / 8 Fl. Oz.
            [product_type] => Treatment
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 13
            [product_name] => 060500 Offects® Hydrating Cleanser Normal to Dry
            [product_price] => 21.45
            [product_size] => 150 mL / 5 Fl. Oz.
            [product_type] => Getting Skin Ready: Scrub
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 14
            [product_name] => 060402 Offects® Exfoliating Cleanser Normal to Oily
            [product_price] => 21.45
            [product_size] => 150 mL / 5 Fl. Oz.
            [product_type] => RX Products
        )

)
```

Output of code above:

```
Array
(
    [Getting Skin Ready: Scrub] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 13
                    [product_name] => 060500 Offects® Hydrating Cleanser Normal to Dry
                    [product_price] => 21.45
                    [product_size] => 150 mL / 5 Fl. Oz.
                    [product_type] => Getting Skin Ready: Scrub
                )

        )

    [Treatment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 12
                    [product_name] => 052200 FoamacleanseTM Gentle Foaming Cleanser
                    [product_price] => 26.95
                    [product_size] => 240 mL / 8 Fl. Oz.
                    [product_type] => Treatment
                )

        )

    [Sun Protection] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 10
                    [product_name] => 050100 NormacleanseTM Cleanser for Normal to Dry Skin
                    [product_price] => 26.95
                    [product_size] => 240 mL / 8 Fl. Oz.
                    [product_type] => Sun Protection
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: can you show your product_types and products array

Comment: I removed the mysql tag. This question has nothing to do with MySQL. I understand you said you got the data from MySQL, but that's immaterial to the problem.

Comment: "its only showing one of them". Are you _sure_ about that?  [See Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/933506565b99af75830329584dc51f71e4b96866) Show the code where you're using/displaying the results.

Comment: I added more info in my original post.

Comment: None of those products have the same `product_type`, so you're either leaving something out, or you don't understand what your program is doing.

Comment: Thats correct.  I am trying to get them into their respective product_type arrays.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually working.  I needed to select more product_types.